# Hive Joining tables using bigint key give wrong result

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I'm joining one table with a view in Hive using "key" variable which is of bigint data type but getting wrong result.

Below is my query

```
select t1.key,t2.key,stcd,zpcd,
(case
when t1.key=t2.key then 'equal'
else 'not_equal'
end) as key_comparision,
from
(select stcd,zpcd,key,release,tm_series_dt 
from level2.final
where key = '7668810213909968440')
as t1
left join 
level2.fincl_view as t2
on t1.key=t2.key;
```

'''

And getting the below results

[image]

Could Anyone please help me to explain why it's picking the wrong record and equating both keys as equal.

Ideally it should give only 1st row as a result but it's giving me two records.

Could anyone please help me to resolve this ?

Comment: can you pls add sample data ? The SQL is correct and your expectation should be correct t2.key for second row should be null.

Comment: Found the issue it is due to the data type difference of key variable in both table in one table it is of varchar(19) type and in one it's of bigint type due to which implicit type conversion occur at the time of join and it gives the wrong result.

Comment: It may be the join column have diffrent data type, you may check that

Answer (score 0):

`t2.key` can't equal `7688***680`

Because, table t1 returns only `768***440` result

`t1 left join t2` only get result table t1, so only result `768***440` appears.

More clear, let's send info ddl.